# How can I create file with permission then change permission

Tags: php, file, permissions, phpunit, file-permissions

I think there is a problem with file owner. But I don't know how should I change the code.

**My Function:**

```
public static function createFile($fileName, $mode = 0777 ){
        if (! is_string( $fileName ) || empty( $fileName )) {
            throw new Exception( "File name must be a string and can not be empty", 923050 );
        }

        $touchResult = touch( $fileName );

        if (! $touchResult) {
            throw new Exception( "Error occurs while touch method was executed", 923052 );
        }

        if (! is_int( $mode ) || $mode > 511) {
            throw new Exception( 'invalid mode value', 923051 );
        } else {
            $chmodResult = chmod( $fileName, $mode );

            if (! $chmodResult) {
                throw new Exception("Error occurs while chmod method was executed", 923052);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Test:**

```
public function testCreateFile(){
        $fileToCreate = __DIR__ . "/../../../../../logs/new.txt";

        //Delete file if exist
        if (file_exists( $fileToCreate )) {
            FileHandler::delete( $fileToCreate );
        }

        //Create file. Default mode 0777
        FileHandler::createFile( $fileToCreate );
        $this->assertFileExists( $fileToCreate );

        $filePermisson = substr( sprintf( '%o', fileperms( $fileToCreate ) ), - 4 );
        $this->assertEquals("0777", $filePermisson);

        //Change permission of existing file
        FileHandler::createFile($fileToCreate, 0775);
        $filePermisson = substr( sprintf( '%o', fileperms( $fileToCreate ) ), - 4 );
        $this->assertEquals("0775", $filePermisson);

    }
```

**Error:**

> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) FileHandlerTest::testCreateFile Failed asserting that '0777'
>   matches expected '0775'.

Comment: You are using the `octdec()` function incorrectly. `octdec( $mode ) > 511` only makes sense if $mode is a string - but it already is an integer with the correct value of the permission. You can directly compare it: `$mode > 511` (decimal integer) or `$mode > 0777` (octal integer). You should probably check for negativ values as well.

Comment: Sven thank you I updated code in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `clearstatcache();` function before `fileperms();` to clear cache